# Error connecting to Azure Blob Storage Service with Java (Status code 405, UnsupportedHttpVerb)

Tags: java, azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to connect to Azure Blob Storage Service from an Azure Function but everything that it returns is a `BlobStorageException`

I used this example: [Azure Storage Blob client library for Java (Create a BlobServiceClient)](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/tree/main/sdk/storage/azure-storage-blob#create-a-blobserviceclient)

Here is my code:

```java
String MY_BLOB_ENDPOINT = "https://mystorageaccount.z13.web.core.windows.net/"

String MY_BLOB_SAS_TOKEN = "?sv=2017-07-29&ss=b&srt=s&sp=rwdc&se=2022-06-10T00:00:00Z&st=2021-06-10T00:00:00Z&spr=https&sig=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

String MY_DEFAULT_CONTAINER_NAME = "test"

BlobServiceClient serviceClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder()
    .endpoint(MY_BLOB_ENDPOINT)
    .sasToken(MY_BLOB_SAS_TOKEN)
    .buildClient();

this.containerClient = serviceClient.
    getBlobContainerClient(MY_DEFAULT_CONTAINER_NAME);

if (!this.containerClient.exists()) {
    this.containerClient.create();
}
```

Here are the logs:

```
... (omitted logs)
[2021-06-26T03:36:28.671Z] Executed 'Functions.upload' (Failed, Id=ffdff367-242e-494a-8303-e9ceeee6a2d7, Duration=5919ms)
[2021-06-26T03:36:28.671Z] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.upload. System.Private.CoreLib: Result: Failure
[2021-06-26T03:36:28.671Z] Exception: BlobStorageException: Status code 405,
                           "<!DOCTYPE html>
                            <html>
                              <head>
                                <title>UnsupportedHttpVerb</title>
                              </head>
                              <body>
                                <h1>The resource doesn't support specified Http Verb.</h1>
                                <p>
                                  <ul>
                                    <li>HttpStatusCode: 405</li>
                                    <li>ErrorCode: UnsupportedHttpVerb</li>
                                    <li>RequestId : 05ac7acf-701e-0026-213c-6adf7e000000</li><li>TimeStamp : 2021-06-26T03:36:28.4852611Z</li>
                                  </ul>
                                </p>
                              </body>
                            </html>"
[2021-06-26T03:36:28.671Z] Stack: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to initialize
[2021-06-26T03:36:28.671Z]      at org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.azure.FunctionInvoker.<init>(FunctionInvoker.java:90)
[2021-06-26T03:36:28.671Z]      at org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.azure.FunctionInvoker.<init>(FunctionInvoker.java:95)
... (omitted logs)
```

Blob Storage Dependency

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-storage-blob</artifactId>
    <version>12.11.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I don't know why it is not working. Is there some additional settings that I need to configure?.

Comment: This is very weird! Can you edit your question and include the values for `MY_BLOB_ENDPOINT`, `MY_BLOB_SAS_TOKEN` and `MY_DEFAULT_CONTAINER_NAME`. Please obfuscate the account name, `sig` portion of your SAS Token before sharing.

Comment: @GauravMantri I changed them.

Comment: Thanks. I have provided an answer. HTH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're getting this error is because you're using incorrect endpoint. Please try by changing:

```
String MY_BLOB_ENDPOINT = "https://mystorageaccount.z13.web.core.windows.net/"
```

to

```
String MY_BLOB_ENDPOINT = "https://mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/"
```

and you should not get the error.

Essentially `https://mystorageaccount.z13.web.core.windows.net/` is a special endpoint for accessing `static website hosted in Azure Blob Storage`. This endpoint maps to `$web` blob container.

To perform any operations on the blob containers and blobs, you will need to use the blob endpoint which should be like `https://mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/`.

Comment: So true. Now it works fine locally but when I deploy it to Azure, in Application Insights I get this [error message](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/2279742b4d307573f369fb35c8eb936301b6b4a9/sdk/storage/azure-storage-common/src/main/java/com/azure/storage/common/implementation/StorageImplUtils.java#L52)
Is this related to the function time zone?

Comment: Can you edit your question and include the code for generating SAS? Also, what's the time zone for your Azure Function?

Comment: It is in UTC-Zero time zone and I generated the SAS token using `Terraform` with `start: 2021-06-10T00:00:00Z` and `expiry: 2022-06-10T00:00:00Z` dates

Comment: Can you share the exact error message? I would recommend posting a separate question for that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your provided SAS Key is valid or gives permision to access the blobs in the storage account

Comment: I used `Terraform` to deploy my Storage Account and generate a SAS Token (from this [link](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/data-sources/storage_account_sas#example-usage)) I've only changed the `start`/ `expiration` dates and the permissions settings `create`, `read`, `write` and `delete` are the unique permissions allowed.